# React-native bluetooth scan: device name is always null

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

I'm building an Android application with React-native and I need the bluetooth to communicate with a particular device.

I'm using this library to scan for devices: https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { PermissionsAndroid, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';    

const ProfileScreen = props => {
  async function requestCameraPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
          message: 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('You can use the camera');
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return false;
    }
  }

  scanAndConnect = () => {
    const permission = requestCameraPermission();

    if (permission) {
      const bluetoothInstance = new BleManager();

      bluetoothInstance.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return
        } else {
          console.log(device);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("permission not granted")
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Profile</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Start scanning"
        onPress={scanAndConnect}/>
      </View>
  )
}
```

Initially I thought it was working, but when I check the console I notice that all the devices found are like this:

```
Device {
    id : "2C:F0:EE:19:27:CF"
    isConnectable : null 
    localName : null
    manufacturerData : "TAAQBQsUluNJ"
    mtu : 23
    name : null
    overflowServiceUUIDs : null
    rssi : -62 
    serviceData : null 
    serviceUUIDs : null 
    solicitedServiceUUIDs : null 
    txPowerLevel : null
    _manager : BleManager
    __proto__ : Object
}
```

Is this result correct? I can't find any way to understand which is my device without informations like `name` or `localName`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Bluetooth LE GATT servers must advertise their names in order for it to be known during scanning. As for identifying the device the id can be used. It is just a bluetooth MAC address.